# IJCADでQueueForGraphicsFlushを呼び出すと例外が発生

Tags: .net, ijcad

IJCAD 2015で.Net APIを使ってます。

図形を作図して、TransactionManager.QueueForGraphicsFlushを呼び出すと例外（eNotImplementedYet）が発生します。同じコードをAutoCAD 2014で実行した場合は問題は発生せずに描画が更新されていました。

何か処理が足りないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

現在のIJCADではTransactionManager.QueueForGraphicsFlush()が実装されていないため例外が発生します。

描画を更新するのであれば、Editor.Regen()を呼び出すといいです。